# How can I check the convergence of the sequence? Does it diverge?

Tags: calculus, analysis

How can I check the convergence of the sequence $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}$? I think that it diverges,because it is bounded below from $\frac{n(n+1)}{2\sqrt{n^2+n}} $ and above from $\frac{n(n+1)}{2\sqrt{n^2+1}}$..Is this correct?

Comment: Try to use integral test.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Now you could work a little with your bounds to make the $\sim \frac{n}{2}$ behaviour more obvious.

Comment: @DanielFischer So then can I use the Squeeze Theorem and find that the limit is $+ \infty$ ??

Comment: Not sure whether the Squeeze theorem covers that situation in the formulation you have, but if you relax your bounds a bit you get $$\frac{n}{2} < a_n < \frac{n+1}{2}.$$

Comment: Call your sequence $(a_n)$. You have observed (lower bound) that $a_n\gt \frac{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}{2}$. That is enough to show divergence to $\infty$. You do not need your (correct) upper bound. Where both bounds would be useful is in showing that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can I also say that $a_n > \frac{n^2(n+1)}{2 \sqrt{n^2+n}}$ ?

Comment: Your earlier one $\frac{n(n+1)}{2\sqrt{n^2+n}}$ was correct, the one with the extra $n$ on top (previous comment) is not. Your earlier one is the same as $\frac{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}{2}$ because of cancellation.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: you can use Squeeze Theorem.

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}+\cdots+\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\cdots+\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$.

Comment: So are the bounds that I have found wrong?

Comment: Nope you just found different bounds.

Comment: Your bounds are tighter, @MaryStar.

Comment: The lower bound here is not strong enough, and we do not need an upper bound.

Comment: So can I use the Squeeze Theorem to find the limit? Is the limit $ + \infty$? So the sequence diverges, or not?

Comment: @DanielFischer Are the bounds (below:)$\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2 \sqrt{n^2+n}}$  and (above:)$\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2 \sqrt{n^2+1}}$ also right?

Comment: @MaryStar The upper bound $\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ is also right (unnecessarily large, but still an upper bound), but $\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2\sqrt{n^2+n}}$ is not a lower bound.

Comment: the upper bound you introduced converges to n instead of 1.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks a lot I want to edit another post

Comment: Your lower bound tends to $1$ and your upper bound tends to $\infty$. What does this tell us? Furthermore, I think you probably want $\sqrt{n^2+n}$ in the denominator on the left and $\sqrt{n^2+1}$ in the denominator on the right.

Comment: @robjohn thanks I fixed it

Comment: @Babgen: I hope you don't mind. I edited the right hand side

Answer (score 2):

Since $n^2\le n^2+k\le\left(n+\frac12\right)^2$ for $0\le k\le n$, we have
$$
\frac1{n+\frac12}\sum_{k=1}^nk\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\le\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nk
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac n2\le\frac{n(n+1)}{2n+1}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\le\frac{n+1}2{}
$$
That is, the sequence diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment. The sum can be estimated as

> $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{\sqrt{n^2+k} }  \sim \int_{1}^{n} \frac{x}{\sqrt{n^2+x} }  dx=\dots\,.$$